# Docker: Map container port to single IPv6-address on host

Tags: linux, networking, docker, ipv6

now that some of my server applications are packed into Docker containers, I'm trying to deploy them on my production servers. My containers should be accessible by IPv4 *and* IPv6 at the same time. Usually that is no problem: If you map container ports to host ports e.g. via docker-compose, Docker will use available IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

My problem is: There is not only one IPv4 and IPv6 address available on my server, but multiple. **My application container should only use *one* specific IPv4 address and *one* specific IPv6 address of the host.** You can bind a container port to a IPv4-address by using the following docker-compose syntax:

```
ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
```

(See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information how to do that with IPv6 addresses. **Is there any way I can bind a container port to a single, *specific* IPv6 address on my Docker host?**

Comment: I haven't used Docker, but I assume the process is similar to VM situation. With VMs, I create a bridge interface, which has host physical interface and VM virtual interface as a member. Then, inside the VM I assign the public IPv6 address which I want the VM to have. Replace the VM with container in the description and you should have the way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.15 of docker-compose you can now use additional colons in the port definition for IPv6:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    ports: 
    - "::1:8080:80"
```

The relevant issue can be found here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2663

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to bind all container exposed ports to 127.0.0.1 and then forward external v4 and v6 IP-connections via HAProxy to 127.0.0.1. Maybe not the nicest way to do it, but a solution for me.